# error message with spring “Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.”

Tags: spring

I'm trying to set up a simple spring application and I'm getting the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from class path resource [NewFile.xml] is invalid; nested e
xception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

I don't find my problem. this is my NewFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-1.0.xsd" >
```

I use Spring Integration 1.0.4, Spring core 2.5.6, and javamail 1.4

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "schema" in the path:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/schema/beans"
```

IIRC only one is required:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works now ! It's a mistake on the documentation of Spring. You can see there http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch23s03.html.

Comment: @ssoltanid Hmm, yes. Being such an old version it's unlikely to be updated, either--unless you have a compelling reason for doing so, I'd really recommend not using Spring 2.5, 2.5.6 was released in 2008, and the current version is 4.0.

Comment: Yes I know, Thanks for your help and advice. It's mandatory to use this version in my company for this projects (because it depends on a project on Java 5), so I have to do like that :(. Thanks a lot !